# "No cast destinations found" in Chromium on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, chromium, chromecast

Why am I getting this error when I try to cast from Chromium on Arch Linux?

[image: No cast destinations found. Need help?]

Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to chrome://flags/#load-media-router-component-extension and change **Load Media Router Component Extension** from *Default* to *Enabled*.

This enables the closed-source code neccesary to use Chromecast. See https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/51832 for more information.